# Divide array into separate variables and pass it to function

Tags: php, arrays

I have the following class:

```
class Foo {
  public function __construct($id, $name, $value) {}
}
```

I want to initialize this class using variables from an array, like:

```
$arr = array(1, 'some name', 'some value');
$fooObj = new Foo($arr);
```

It should work like a spread operator from ES6 in javascript:

```
callFunc(...arr);
```

Is this possible?

Comment: @Super Nope, the reverse is being asked here.

Answer (score 4):

In PHP >= 5.6.0, use [argument unpacking](http://php.net/manual/en/migration56.new-features.php#migration56.new-features.splat) as you show for JavaScipt with `...`:

```
$fooObj = new Foo(...$arr);
```

For previous versions you can use `call_user_func_array()`, but unfortunately not to instantiate an object and pass to the constructor.

According to [deceze](https://stackoverflow.com/users/476/deceze) you can use [ReflectionClass::newInstanceArgs](http://php.net/manual/en/reflectionclass.newinstanceargs.php) for instantiating your object:

```
$class  = new ReflectionClass('Foo');
$fooObj = $class->newInstanceArgs($arr);
```

Comment: The `call_user_func_array` equivalent for instantiating a class is [`ReflectionClass::newInstanceArgs`](http://php.net/manual/en/reflectionclass.newinstanceargs.php).

Answer (score -2):

The spread operator allows you to pass a list of parameters, and the function take these parameters as an array. In **PHP** you can use the *variable argument list operator* "`...`".

http://docs.php.net/manual/en/functions.arguments.php#functions.variable-arg-list

Example:

```
<?php
function sum(...$numbers) {
    $acc = 0;
    foreach ($numbers as $n) {
        $acc += $n;
    }
    return $acc;
}

echo sum(1, 2, 3, 4);
?>
```

Using your example:

```
class Foo {
  var $id;
  var $name;
  var $value;
  public function __construct(...$params) {
    $this->id=$params[0];
    $this->name=$params[1];
    $this->value=$params[2];
  }
}
```

Then call :

```
$var=new Foo(1, 'some name', 'some value');
```

In your case, you are trying to pass an array of parameters to a function. In this case you can omit the "..." operator and pass the elements:

```
class Foo {
  var $id;
  var $name;
  var $value;
  public function __construct($params) {
    $this->id=$params[0];
    $this->name=$params[1];
    $this->value=$params[2];
  }
}
```

Then call :

```
$arr = array(1, 'some name', 'some value');
$fooObj = new Foo($arr);
```